# Adding to database using Oledb Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, oledb

when i hit the add button to insert a new book, i get an error at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. Am i missing anything?

```
protected void btnAddBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Bookdb.accdb";
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Books (Title, Author, Price, Edition) VALUES (@Title, @Author, @Price, @Edition)");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TextBox1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", TextBox2.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", TextBox3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edition", TextBox4.Text);


                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, OleDb parameters should not be named in the string, just marked with a `?` and added to the parameter list in the same order. `new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Books (Title, Author, Price, Edition) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");`

Comment: That's strange, your code and command text seem to be correct. Also the parameter placeholder, while are not in the form expected by OleDb are accepted when you connect to an Access Database. The only problem could be the Price field. If Price is a numeric field on the database then you better convert it when adding the value to the parameter @price. For example `Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text)`

Comment: still the same error   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason that I can find as a possible failure for your code is if the Price field is a numeric field in your database table. You are creating a parameter with AddWithValue and this method creates a parameter whose datatype is derived from the datatype of the value passed. You pass a string (TextBox3.Text) and so AddWithValue creates a string parameter.

You could try to force the AddWithValue to create a numeric parameter with

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text));
```

(Of course assuming a decimal Price column)

Comment: Thanks but I'm still getting Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Answer (score -1):

Right before you call `conn.Open()`, you need to call `cmd.Prepare()`, so that all the parameters you set are actually loaded into the SQL statement.

Comment: Prepare requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: In that case, move conn.Open() above the line where you create OleDbCommand cmd = ... But keep the cmd.Prepare() below all the AddWithValue lines.

Comment: conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TextBox1.Text); still gives an error Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement